# ActionBar SearchView styling in Android

Tags: android, android-actionbar

I'm trying to make a search box in my action bar with a white background, black or dark grey icons (for the magnifying glass & x icons), with a black background in the actionbar and the overflow button white.  I also want to use the Holo theme for the app as a whole.

Because I can't access the searchview's icons, I have to use XML styles to theme it.
When I try this in one of my res/values/style.xml file:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Overflow</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_color</item>
</style>

<style name="Overflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

[image]
the result has the icons light gray (from the light theme) instead of the dark that I want, and the overflow button is not visible.  If I try this:

```
<style name="CustomActionBarTheme" parent="android:style/Theme.Holo.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/MyActionBar</item>
    <item name="android:actionOverflowButtonStyle">@style/Overflow</item>
</style>

<!-- ActionBar styles -->
<style name="MyActionBar"
       parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_color</item>
</style>

<style name="Overflow" parent="@android:style/Widget.ActionButton.Overflow">
    <item name="android:src">@drawable/ic_menu_moreoverflow_normal_holo_dark</item>
</style>
```

[image]

the result has the icons dark like I wanted, but requires that I use the light theme in my app everywhere, and the overflow button is again not visible.